# How to make a three image grid system?

Tags: html, css, grid, alignment, photos

What I'm trying to do is put three images (this one: http://baseframe.co/a/img/animus.png) in a three column grid system with two layers.

I really struggle with putting divs next to each other so if anyone can explain it alongside the problem I'm having about, it'd be really helpful!

Thanks,
Aaron

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
`http://codepen.io/aaronmtx/pen/PGdGyA`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `display: inline-block`. So...

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

Where each `<div>` and `<img ...>` is styled...

```
div {
    display: inline-block;   
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is a very simple approach as you will likely want some additional styles to be applied. Constrain the width of each `<div>` to say 33% to get three equal sized images in a row. Then repeat the HTML so it will break the next three images on a new line. Applying a width of 100% to each `<img ...>` will ensure they don't spill out of their respective `div` containers.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Hi, appreciate the response! I'm just not too sure how I could apply that to my code. I just updated my post with my code (which I should have done in the first place). If you have any ideas, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Done, sorry! :)

Comment: You've got an error in your HTML. You have an extra closing </div> at the end of your <div class="project-2"> Which is closing <div class="project-wrapper"> prematurely. Check out for http://codepen.io/andrewtanner1987/pen/yaxakg for clarification.

Comment: Yes! All fixed! Really appreciate the help!